# how to build my own mp3 player (with js)

Tags: javascript, html

i want to build my own mp3 player, that i can change song, and change the current position in the song,
i want it to be supported in all browsers, so I can't relay on the audio tag.
and all the solutions I founded so far base on it

i managed to found out this:

```
<object
classid="clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" id='player2' height=75>

<param name="CurrentPosition" value="50" />
<param name="ShowPositionControls" value="false" />
<param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true" />
<param name="AutoStart" value="0" />
<param name="Filename" value="music/backstreet boys - one in a million.mp3" />
</object>
```

but. there's two problems:

1. the parameter 'CurrentPosition' doesn't seems to be affecting
2. no refrence i founded is good. no propery (in js) for current posion i founded is not working

Answer (score 0):

use actionscript (with flash/flex ofc). Checkout the flash.media package (and SoundMixer.computeSpectrum if you want to add some kind of visualisations). There's really much you can do with flash that's still not available in js.

Comment: i know flash (and AS) a little.. but how can i load the songs from the server, and tell him wicth songs to play.. I know flash as a close box